# How to reshape a numpy vector of arbitrary length into a square matrix without knowing shape of square

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

How to reshape a 1d numpy vector into a 2d square matrix without specifying the target numbers of rows and columns of the latter?

For example, given an vector of length 9, I know in my mind that it can be converted to a 3x3 matrix, but that vector could in fact be of any length (yet compliable to a square matrix conversion), so I do not know the target number 3 in advance.

Comment: You can check if the original length is a perfect square and apply `reshape` accordingly.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: If you have an array of length `n`, you can check if it has a integer square root. If so, you can use that as dimensions for your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's a 2d vector and we are not sure whether it's horizontal (1,n) or vertical (n,1).

```
a_len = max(a.shape)
a_len_sqrt = int(np.sqrt(a_len))
a = a.reshape((a_len_sqrt, a_len_sqrt))
```

Comment: this fixes the integer problem. plus the last line  should be `a.reshape`?

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the square before, assuming the square is integer and it is actually convertible:

```
n = len(arr)
r = math.sqrt(n)
arr.reshape((r,r))
```